# Error Message of Bean Provider

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, cucumber

I am using eclipse ide for cucumber with selenium webdriver to run the project. but it gave me error message below:

Failure in before hook:Annotation.setUp()
Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/deltaspike/core/api/provider/BeanProvider

Anyone have a idea to sort this error. Please need to sort this out soon.

Thank you in advance...please please help me...

Comment: Can you provide your code that throws this error?

Comment: @Marit, I had reinstall eclipse and it works. I think it was somewhere else config problem.
Thank you very much for the reply.